# When I try to run the following code I am unable to return to command prompt in matlab

Tags: matlab, random

I am new to matlab.I wrote the following code.The problem is that the loop is not terminating.Please help me find out the problem

```
actualvalue = randn(2000,10);
reward = zeros(2000,10,1000);
for i=1:2000
    for j=1:10
        for k=1:1000
            mean = actualvalue(i,j);
            reward(i,j,k) = normrnd(mean,1);
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: You are running `normrnd` a lot of times. If you reduce the inner-most loop's index to 10, it returns in a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done without loops, which is usually faster:

```
reward = bsxfun(@plus, actualvalue, randn(2000,10,1000));
```

To see how this works, note that a normal random variable with mean `mu` and standard deviation `1` is just a standardized (0-mean, 1-standard deviation) normal random variable to which `mu` is added. This addition can be done efficiently with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). Using [`randn`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) instead of `normrnd` also saves some time, as `normrnd` just calls `randn` with some overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without for loops:

```
reward=normrnd(repmat(actualvalue,1,1,1000),1);
```

`repmat(actualvalue,1,1,1000)` adds a third dimension, so now we have a 3D matrix that is just 1000 copies of the matrix `actualvalue`, and we can give this as input for `normrnd`, and it will directly generate the `reward` matrix of the same size with the "expanded" `actualvalue` means and unit variance.